# aiboが指示待ちから復帰しない

Tags: aibo-developer

aiboの指示待ちから復帰するをクリックしても指示待ち状態が続いたため、首のオフボタンをおしたところ、ｸﾞﾘｰﾝのまま点滅状態が続いています。どうしたらいいでしょうか？困っています。

Answer (score 1):

aibo デベロッパーサポート担当です。

首の LED が緑色に点滅したまま動かない場合は、
下記をご参照ください。

https://knowledge.support.sony.jp/electronics/support/articles/00203896

今後とも aibo デベロッパープログラムをどうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

aibo デベロッパーサポートチーム

Comment: こちらの回答には外部リンクの情報しか無いようです。将来的にリンク切れが起こってもaiboさんの回答の価値が失われないよう、リンク先に書かれている情報の要点を回答に含めるなどご一考くださいませ。[「良い回答を書くには？」](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)の「リンクの文脈を提示する」もご一読くだされば幸いです。